# How to implement DataTables Fixed Header feature?

Tags: html, css, datatables

I'm using the DataTables plugin and would like to have my table with a fixed header.  There have been other questions like this posted in the past, but even with those questions, I still could not get it to work. I'm not sure what the issue could be...Maybe I have competing CSS or a missing CDN(that I'm not aware of).

I would appreciate any help here. Thank You

https://jsfiddle.net/k25m6ds0/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
            "searching": true,
            "pageLength": 50,
            "paging": true,
            "info": false,
            fixedHeader: {
                header: true
            }
        })
    });
```

```css
html,
            body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%
        }

        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .footer {
            background-color: #003366;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            height: 30px;
        }

        #footer-center {
            color: white;
        }

        #footer-right {
            float: right;
            color: blue;
        }

        .navbar-nav li:hover>.dropdown-menu {
            display: block;
            content: none;
        }


        .dropdown-menu.show {
            background-color: #f5f6f7;
        }

        header {
            height: 75px;
            background: red;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 500;
        }

        nav {
            background-color: #262626;
            height: 60px;
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
        }

        thead tr th,
            tbody tr td {
            width: 40 px;
            min-width: 40px;
            max-width: 40px;
            word-break: break-all;
        }

        table th {
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            background: #fff;
            text-align: center;
        }

        table {
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        main {
            width: 90%;
            margin: auto;
            flex: 1;
            padding-top: 75;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        td {
            text-align: center;
        }

        table tr td:first-child {
            text-align: left;
            padding-left: 25px;
        }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
        <title>Album example for Bootstrap</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> <img src="#" height="30" width="30" class="d-inline-block align-top"> Website</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Office</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
    <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="th-sm">Name
          </th>
          <th class="th-sm">Position
          </th>
          <th class="th-sm">Office
          </th>
          <th class="th-sm">Age
          </th>
          <th class="th-sm">Start date
          </th>
          <th class="th-sm">Salary
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Airi Satou</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009/09/15</td>
          <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sonya Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008/12/13</td>
          <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jena Gaines</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2008/12/19</td>
          <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
          <td>Support Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2013/03/03</td>
          <td>$342,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Charde Marshall</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2008/10/16</td>
          <td>$470,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2012/12/18</td>
          <td>$313,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>2010/03/17</td>
          <td>$385,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Silva</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2012/11/27</td>
          <td>$198,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Paul Byrd</td>
          <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2010/06/09</td>
          <td>$725,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gloria Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2009/04/10</td>
          <td>$237,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2012/10/13</td>
          <td>$132,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dai Rios</td>
          <td>Personnel Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>2012/09/26</td>
          <td>$217,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
          <td>Development Lead</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2011/09/03</td>
          <td>$345,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Yuri Berry</td>
          <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>2009/06/25</td>
          <td>$675,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
          <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2011/12/12</td>
          <td>$106,450</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2010/09/20</td>
          <td>$85,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
          <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/10/09</td>
          <td>$1,200,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>2010/12/22</td>
          <td>$92,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2010/11/14</td>
          <td>$357,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2011/06/07</td>
          <td>$206,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fiona Green</td>
          <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>2010/03/11</td>
          <td>$850,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shou Itou</td>
          <td>Regional Marketing</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>2011/08/14</td>
          <td>$163,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michelle House</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2011/06/02</td>
          <td>$95,400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Suki Burks</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2009/10/22</td>
          <td>$114,500</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    </main>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="footer-center">Copyright © My Company
                    <div id="footer-right"><a href="#" class="text-muted">Back to top</a></div>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see there are several code issues.

1) You need to add the following script tag `<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>`

2) You need to add the following css `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">`

3) You have some duplicate `<script>` tags like jquery is added multiple times, there are some tags at the bottom of the page as well.

4) It is recommended the jQuery should be the first `<script>` tag.

Finally, here is the working copy in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zwuq20cp/

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
        "searching": true,
        "pageLength": 50,
        "paging": true,
        "info": false,
        "fixedHeader": {
         "headerOffset": 75
        }
    })
});
```

```css
    html,
        body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%
    }

    body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .footer {
        background-color: #003366;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        height: 30px;
    }

    #footer-center {
        color: white;
    }

    #footer-right {
        float: right;
        color: blue;
    }

    .navbar-nav li:hover>.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        content: none;
    }


    .dropdown-menu.show {
        background-color: #f5f6f7;
    }

    header {
        height: 75px;
        background: red;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 500;
    }

    nav {
        background-color: #262626;
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    }

    thead tr th,
        tbody tr td {
        width: 40 px;
        min-width: 40px;
        max-width: 40px;
        word-break: break-all;
    }

    table th {
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        background: #fff;
        text-align: center;
    }

    table {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    main {
        width: 90%;
        margin: auto;
        flex: 1;
        padding-top: 75;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    td {
        text-align: center;
    }

    table tr td:first-child {
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 25px;
    }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
    <title>Album example for Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> <img src="#" height="30" width="30" class="d-inline-block align-top"> Website</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Office</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    <main>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="th-sm">Name
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Position
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Office
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Age
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Start date
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Salary
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2012/11/27</td>
      <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2010/06/09</td>
      <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2009/04/10</td>
      <td>$237,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/10/13</td>
      <td>$132,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dai Rios</td>
      <td>Personnel Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>2012/09/26</td>
      <td>$217,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
      <td>Development Lead</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2011/09/03</td>
      <td>$345,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yuri Berry</td>
      <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>2009/06/25</td>
      <td>$675,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Caesar Vance</td>
      <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2011/12/12</td>
      <td>$106,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doris Wilder</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2010/09/20</td>
      <td>$85,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
      <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/10/09</td>
      <td>$1,200,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>2010/12/22</td>
      <td>$92,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2010/11/14</td>
      <td>$357,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2011/06/07</td>
      <td>$206,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fiona Green</td>
      <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>48</td>
      <td>2010/03/11</td>
      <td>$850,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shou Itou</td>
      <td>Regional Marketing</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>2011/08/14</td>
      <td>$163,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michelle House</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2011/06/02</td>
      <td>$95,400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Suki Burks</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>2009/10/22</td>
      <td>$114,500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

   </main>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="footer-center">Copyright © My Comapany
                <div id="footer-right"><a href="#" class="text-muted">Back to top</a></div>
                <div style="clear: both"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I appreciate that Priyank! Thank you for the for the feedback too.

Comment: I have another question. I hope you can answer. How would this work if I have xscroll on? Xscroll is the horizontal scroll option

Comment: I have not tried it with your code, but in one of my previous projects, I faced an issue where fixed header remained in place and table below was horizontally scrolling. I was not able to solve it though. You can post it as another question on SO hopefully someone will know the answer!

Comment: I just realized that with your answer I lost functionality to my mobile dropdown. You can see that its kind of working in my original JSfiddle (although there is a slightly prob with it that I know how to fix) but with yours the mobile dropdown is completely unfunctional. How would I get that back?  Also, update on my other situation...I guess others are saying that the horizontal scroll is not compatible with the fixed header. Unfortunately.

Comment: @NickT, I guess you mean the menu on top right? Just add the following to your head section, it will start working again. `<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` I deleted this by mistake.

Comment: Thanks man! Doing that brought back the functionality. I also removed the `height: 60px;` in the `nav` section of the CSS, and now it's back to normal.